# Proposal to delete [radio-band] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I'm thinking the tag [radio-band](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-band) is not especially useful. It's not clear what it means for a question to be tagged with it, and it's an attractive nuisance for newcomers who think “I'm asking a radio question, so I'll tag it with a 'radio' tag”.

There are five questions:

- [How do I find out what bands are open?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/2001/how-do-i-find-out-what-bands-are-open) — covered by [propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation).
- [Amatuer Bands (400 Mhz to 4.4 Ghz)](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/amatuer-bands-400-mhz-to-4-4-ghz) — This is a “I want to do radio things, how do I do it within the rules?” question. It could use more relevant tags, but [legal](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) might be a suitable addition.
- [How do I radio?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/how-do-i-radio) [closed] — Off topic, disregard.
- [What bands and modes will give me voice at 3,000 miles?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/574/what-bands-and-modes-will-give-me-voice-at-3-000-miles) — Another [propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation) question, decently tagged anyway.
- [What are amateur radio bands?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/309/what-are-amateur-radio-bands) [closed] — Marginally off-topic; could be tagged with [jargon](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jargon) instead.

Does anyone object to my eliminating the tag?

Is there a natural category our tags don't otherwise have that is best served by [radio-band](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-band) or perhaps by a new tag with a better name?

Comment: Seems a plenty reasonable proposal to me, but I'll let the community have a say before doing so by mod-hammer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I was planning to hand-retag each one since some of them are short on other tags and there's only five.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody objected, I have now removed the tag from all six (one just posted) questions that had it, along with other retagging and edits as I saw fit.